# Function mapping with Monads

Tags: haskell, monads

I have the following code :

```
type Mapper a k v = a -> [(k,v)]
type Reducer k v = k -> [v] -> [v]


mapReduce :: Ord k => Mapper a k v -> Reducer k v -> [a] -> [(k,[v])]
mapReduce m r = reduce r . shuffleKeys . concatMap (map listifyVal . m)
  where listifyVal (k,v) = (k,[v])
        shuffleKeys = Map.fromListWith (++)
        reduce r = Map.toList . Map.mapWithKey r
```

I'm given a `Monad` types

```
   type MapperM m a k v = a -> m [(k,v)]
   type ReducerM m k v = k -> [v] -> m [v]
```

And I need to convert the existing code to use `Monad`

```
mapReduceM :: (Ord k, Monad m) => MapperM m a k v -> ReducerM m k v -> [a] -> m [(k,[v])]
```

I'm stuck on converting the expression  `concatMap (map listifyVal . m)`
I wrote this helper function

```
listifyValM:: (Ord k, Monad m) => m(k,v) ->  m(k,[v])                        
listifyValM mkv = do
                    (k,v) <- mkv
                    return (k,[v])
```

and tried

```
 mapReduceM :: (Ord k, Monad m) => MapperM m a k v -> ReducerM m k v -> [a] -> m [(k,[v])]
 mapReduceM m r input =  do      
                            let step0 =  (map listifyValM )                                                  
                            return []
```

But I can't get even this (very partial) simple thing to work as a starter. 
I get :

```
  Could not deduce (Ord k0) arising from a use of `listifyValM'
  from the context: (Ord k, Monad m)
    bound by the type signature for:
```

I'm probably missing something basic regarding `mapping` over `Monads`.

Comment: You write `map listifyValM`, but since you do not pass a the list to map over, it thus does not know for what `m`, `k` and `v` it needs to "create" the function That is the problem. It has nothing to do with monads itself.

Comment: Can anyone give me a hint how to approach this problem in general ?

Comment: For the error you're getting, just give your helper function a type signature with class constraints: `step0 :: (Monad m, Ord k) => [m (k, v)] -> [m (k, [v])]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing `mapReduceM` from scratch may be easier than trying to mechanically convert `mapReduce`.  You want:

```
mapReduceM :: (Monad m, Ord k) => MapperM m a k v -> ReducerM m k v -> [a] -> m [(k,[v])]
mapReduceM m r as = ...
```

So, let's assume arguments of the following types and try to build the function:

```
m :: a -> m [(k,v)]
r :: k -> [v] -> m [v]
as :: [a]
```

It can be helpful to create a skeleton file that uses concrete types which will let us type check expressions in GHCi:

```
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map

data A
data K = K deriving (Eq, Ord)
data V
data M a
instance Functor M
instance Applicative M
instance Monad M

m :: A -> M [(K,V)]
m = undefined
r :: K -> [V] -> M [V]
r = undefined
as :: [A]
as = undefined
```

Obviously, we need to pass the elements of `as` to the only available function that can take them, namely `m`.  The standard way of applying a monadic function `a -> m b` to a list `[a]` is to perform a traversal, using `mapM` or `traverse`.  (In the old days, the former was for monads and the latter was for applicatives, but now that all monads are applicatives, `traverse` is preferred.)  Specifically, with this skeleton loaded, we can type check this expression in GHCi:

```
> :t traverse m as
traverse m as :: M [[(K, V)]]
```

To collapse the lists of lists, we want to apply `concat` "under" the monad.  Fortunately, monads are functors, so `fmap` (or its synonym `(<$>)`) can do it:

```
> :t concat <$> traverse m as
concat <$> traverse m as :: M [(K, V)]
```

Now, we want to load this into a map by common keys.  In other word, we want to apply the pure function:

```
combineByKey :: [(K, V)] -> Map K [V]
combineByKey = Map.fromListWith (++) . map (\(k,v) -> (k,[v]))
```

under the monad:

```
> :t combineByKey . concat <$> traverse m as
combineByKey . concat <$> traverse m as :: M (Map K [V])
```

Now, we want to apply the reduction `r` to the map.  This is a little tricky.  If we try to apply `mapWithKey` under the monad the same way we did with `concat` and `combineByKey`, we get an extra unwanted monad layer:

```
> :t Map.mapWithKey r . combineByKey . concat <$> traverse m as
Map.mapWithKey r . combineByKey . concat <$> traverse m as
  :: M (Map K (M [V]))
     ^---------^---------- two monad layers
```

Here, `do` notation can help us work through the process:

```
do mymap <- combineByKey . concat <$> traverse m as
   ...
```

Here, `mymap` is pulled out of the monad and so has type:

```
mymap :: Map K [V]
mymap = undefined
```

If we used `mapWithKey` to apply the reducer:

```
> Map.mapWithKey r mymap
Map.mapWithKey r mymap :: Map K (M [V])
```

we have a structure of monadic elements.  Because `Map` is traversable, we can pull the monad to the outside with `sequence`:

```
> sequence $ Map.mapWithKey r mymap
sequence $ Map.mapWithKey r mymap :: M (Map K [V])
```

This is *almost* the return value we wanted from `mapReduceM`.  We just need to change the map to a list under the monad:

```
> Map.toList <$> (sequence $ Map.mapWithKey r mymap)
Map.toList <$> (sequence $ Map.mapWithKey r mymap) :: M [(K, [V])]
```

In the end, our definition of `mapReduceM` is the completed do-block:

```
mapReduceM :: (Monad m, Ord k) => MapperM m a k v -> ReducerM m k v -> [a] -> m [(k,[v])]
mapReduceM m r as = do
  mymap <- combineByKey . concat <$> traverse m as
  Map.toList <$> (sequence $ Map.mapWithKey r mymap)
  where combineByKey :: (Ord k) => [(k, v)] -> Map k [v]
        combineByKey = Map.fromListWith (++) . map (\(k,v) -> (k,[v]))
```

This can be converted to a point-free form like so:

```
import Control.Monad

mapReduceM :: (Monad m, Ord k) => MapperM m a k v -> ReducerM m k v -> [a] -> m [(k,[v])]
mapReduceM m r =
  traverse m >=>                       -- apply the mapper
  pure . combineByKey . concat >=>     -- combine keys
  sequence . Map.mapWithKey r >=>      -- reduce
  pure . Map.toList                    -- convert to list

  where combineByKey :: (Ord k) => [(k, v)] -> Map k [v]
        combineByKey = Map.fromListWith (++) . map (\(k,v) -> (k,[v]))
```